Is there a way around clone in this example?
I have the piece of code below, which works fine, but I am a bit bothered by the need for clone inside the for loop. In principle, the vector is no longer needed after a.clear() is called, so it could be consumed inside this loop, but the code won't compile without clone. Is there a clever way around this, that moves self.a[i].v into the new AStruct instead of cloning it?
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct AStruct {
    v: Vec<i32>,
    w: i32,
}

struct TestStruct {
    a: Vec<AStruct>,
}

impl TestStruct {
    fn test(&mut self) {
        let mut h: HashMap<Vec<i32>, i32> = HashMap::new();
        for x in &self.a {
            let key = x.v.clone();
            let entry = h.entry(key).or_insert(0);
            *entry += x.w;
        }
        self.a.clear();
        for (key, value) in h {
            self.a.push( AStruct {
                v: key,
                w: value,
            } );
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = AStruct {
        v: vec![1, 2, 3],
        w: 4,
    };
    let mut t = TestStruct { a: vec![a] };
    t.test();
    println!("{:?}", t.a);
}


sounds like you want Vec::drain?

@drewtato I tried to replace the corresponding line with let key = x.v.drain(..).collect(); but that results in error[E0596]: cannot borrow `x.v` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference. Am I using this wrong?

You probably want to drain self.a. I.e. for x in &self.a → for x in self.a.drain(..)

Thanks to the comments, I ended up with the solution
impl TestStruct {
    fn test(&mut self) {
        let mut h: HashMap<Vec<i32>, i32> = HashMap::new();
        for x in self.a.drain(..) {
            let key = x.v;
            let entry = h.entry(key).or_insert(0);
            *entry += x.w;
        }
        for (key, value) in h {
            self.a.push( AStruct {
                v: key,
                w: value,
            } );
        }
    }
}

(edited to reflect comment by cafce25)

You don't need to .drain(..).collect() just for x in self.a.drain(..) is enough and does not create an intermediate Vec with an extraneous allocation.
